# Using beautifulsoup to extract text information from table in webpage

Tags: javascript, python, beautifulsoup

I have a table from a webpage that I am attempting to extract the text data from.

A snippet of the HTML table looks as follows:
[image]

You can see the following table headings 'Effective Date', 'Type', 'Note' that I would like to extract text data from.

I have used the following code to attempt to extract the data:

```
content = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(content)

for child in soup.find_all('table')[7].children:
    for td in child:
        print(td.text)
```

However, am met with a `'str' object has no attribute 'text'`

Based on this HTML layout, what is the best way to find the right table - iterate through it i.e. the td's and select the text data appropriately? (Note that for the 'Note Headings' there are also 'br's' that may need to be iterated through). Thanks.

Comment: Can you give the site address for testing, if it's a public site...?

Comment: @goalie1998 - I am afraid the site is a private one that can only be accessed securely

Comment: Oh HIPAA is overrated anyway...

Comment: @goalie1998 - absolutely and hinders progress in the field of healthcare analytics!

Comment: can you put the line you use for the soup object: so what do you have after `soup = ` Just that 1 line and I might be able to help

Comment: @chitown88 - thanks, I have added the lines. Please see above.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that. After the `content = driver.page_source`, try and see if pandas will pull out the tables. If there are `<table>` tags, it will put them into a list of tables.

So:

```
import pandas as pd

content = driver.page_source
dfs = pd.read_html(content)
```

See if that returns your table in that list.

Comment: @chittown88 - thanks for your response. The tables read in do not have the text content that I want to extract, unfortunately:

Comment: @chittown88 - any other ways I can play around with to see how I can extract the text data?